# How to add a string to QCombobox

Tags: qt, qcombobox

Normally I would add items to a QCombobox by saying:

```
QCombobox cbb;
cbb.addItem("Hello");
```

But if I try this I get an error:

```
QComboBox cbb;
QString * s = new QString("hallo");
cbb.addItem(s);

error: no matching function for call to 'QComboBox::addItem(QString*&)'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use dynamic memory allocation with `QString`. `QString` handles memory management for the string internally - if you allocate the memory for the `QString` object yourself, you also need to take care of releasing the memory.

In your case, simply use

```
QComboBox cbb;
QString s = "hallo";
cbb.addItem(s);
```

Comment: is there any way to add the item on top instead of at the bottom?

Comment: Did you try `insertItem(0, s)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a pointer you'll need to de-referenciate it first: cbb.addItem(*s); Anyway why are you allocating a QString on heap and the comboBox (which most likely will get a parent) on stack?